# Issue getting blockhash using browser version of SolanaWeb3

Tags: web3.js

I'm using the Browser version of SolanaWeb3, when I run the below code I get the error

```
connection.ts:3870 Uncaught (in promise) Error: failed to get recent blockhash: TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at Connection.getLatestBlockhash (connection.ts:3870:13)
```

Code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.onload = async function () {
    //let rpc = "https://api.devnet.solana.com";
    let rpc = "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com";
    let connection = new solanaWeb3.Connection(rpc);
    let blockhash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash("finalized").blockhash;
    console.log("recentBlockhash: ", blockhash);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved issue, couldn't use that RPC, was able to see was not connecting to RPC in Network Tab of Chrome, used Quicknode RPC instead and worked.